# using SharePoint survey list

Tags: list, survey-list

I have question in the subject of list from type of survey.
After I created a number of those lists

**1.**
I want to use the results of the survey in order to use the next data,
for instance:
How many people chose the answer 3 in question number 5? tec.

**2.**
now I want to create a list that all her item will be from character of survey
how can i do it?

thanks:)
Liron

Comment: Liron: I, for one, can't really understand your questions. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create a second list in order to view the survey results. Do you want to show the survey results without an option to respond to the survey? If so, edit a page and add a list view web part for the survey to that page. Edit the web part and select the View to be either Graphical Summary or All Responses.